# 1318 - Incorrect number of arguments for PROCEDURE

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, syntax-error

```
DROP PROCEDURE `ModificarUsuario`//
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `ModificarUsuario`(
   IN `Aid` INT,
   IN `Aced` VARCHAR(100),
   IN `Anombre` VARCHAR(100), 
   IN `Acargo` VARCHAR(100), 
   IN `Acedula` VARCHAR(100), 
   IN `Ausuario` VARCHAR(100),
   IN `Apass` VARCHAR(100),
   OUT `res` VARCHAR(10) )
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(usuario) INTO res FROM `usuario` WHERE `cedula`=Aced and `id`<>Aid;
    IF  res =0 THEN
       UPDATE `usuario` SET cedula=Aced, nombre=Anombre, cargo=Acargo, usuario=Ausuario, contrasena=Apass WHERE cedula=Acedula;
    END IF;
END
```

When I use this procedure I get the error "expected 8, got 7." I don't understand this, if we look at the code there are 7 input parameters and one out parameter. It seems that the out parameter needs to be specified as well when calling the procedure, any idea why?

Comment: show your query for execute stored procedure

Comment: CALL ModificarUsuario('6','9123','Sandra','Profesor','12345','sandru','sdf')

Comment: You need to pass 8 parameters. 8th parameter will be variable will have the return value.

Comment: CALL ModificarUsuario('6','9123','Sandra','Profesor','12345','sandru','sdf',a) If I enter a variable 8th I get this error. 1414 - OUT or INOUT argument 8 for routine bdservidor.ModificarUsuario is not a variable or NEW pseudo-variable in BEFORE trigger

Answer (score 11):

**You need to reference the out parameter**

```
CALL ModificarUsuario('6','9123','Sandra','Profesor','12345','sandru','sdf',@a)
```

**to see result execute** `Select @a` **or** `Select res`

Comment: Any idea why in MySQL Workbench 6.3 the @a value won't update? Say I have a very simple `if then else` in the stored procedure. I know the value should change but it remains the same when it shouldn't. Why? THANKS!

Comment: Since proc have a output, we need to provide a temp variable to see the output